# Whether the end-point is x% closer to an arbitrary point when compared to the start-point

Tags: algorithm, math, pseudocode

I am having three coordinate locations A(x1, y1), B(x2, y2) and C(x3, y3). A is the starting location, B is the end location and C is the arbitrary coordinate location. Now I want to calculate whether the end-location(B) at least 25% closer to the point-location(C) when compared to start-location(A).

Can someone write pseudocode for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple vector geometry:

The squared distance d2 from A to B is (Ax - Bx)^2 + (Ay - By)^2

So B to C is 25% less than A to C if:

```
sqrt(d2(A,C)) * 0.75 >= sqrt(d2(B,C))
```

And simplified, so you dont need to deal with roots:

```
d2(A, C) * 0.75^2 >= d2(B, C)
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you use some kind of floating point numbers:

```
distance_to_a := dist(A, B)
distance_to_c := dist(C, B)

if distance_to_c <= 0.75 * distance_to_a:
    output "C at least 25% closer"
else:
    output "C not at least 25% closer"
```

Now assuming you want to use euclidean distance, define the following:

```
def dist(A: Point, B: Point):
    return sqrt((A.x-B.x)^2 + (A.y-B.y)^2)
```